# compile class without dependency(imported class) in build path

Tags: java, jar

Is it possible and correct to export a class as .jar when the class it depends on is not in the class path. To be specific, I am using eclipse to export the class as jar file with the dependent class not in the class path.

Comment: yes, is it ok if jar is created with eclipse showing errors. will the jar be usable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have compile errors in your classes, Eclipse would still allow you to export your classes as jar (there is a checkbox that you can check to allow this while exporting) but that will not be usable. As the `jar` file mainly contains the `.class` files which are nothing but the compiled source files (`.java` files).

Comment: thanks Kuldeep, I tried this and found that though the jar was being made, it didnt work when accessed through my app. This means that we need to have the build path set properly before making the jar file so that it is usable.

Answer (score 2):

Provided the Java class compiles, you can put the .class files in a JAR without it's dependencies.